# Converting floats to ints reliably

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I have an application that uses floats to handle distances, for example, 2.5f is 2.5 meters (250 centimeters). Now I want to interface with that application without using floats via network. I can't change the fact that it uses floats, but I can make it send and read ints to and from my second application.

As the smallest unit I could use a centimeter, which would be 0.01f. The two applications would then communicate that value as the integer "1", and application 1 would convert it to and from float.

My question is: is it possible to do that conversion with 100% reliability? Is there a way to guarantee that what's 12345 on one side will always be 123,45 on the other and vice versa, ideally without considerably impacting the performance?

I'm aware of the floating point precision problems, and some initial tests of mine seem like it's not possible, but I'm hoping there might be a way that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Well you've already got a problem in that you can't precisely represent (say) 1.01 metres. That might be represented by a value *just less than* 1.01, or *just more than* 1.01, which could affect the rounding.

Comment: *Now I want to interface with that application without using floats via network.* why do you want to do that?

Comment: Does C# have an equivalent of Java's Float.floatToIntBits(float) method? If so, and if both sides are using the same floating point format, that may be both efficient and reliable.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Because the second application can't handle floats.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan If I understand the purpose of that function correctly, you're right that you could reliably transfer the float back and forth without changing its value, but you still couldn't convert it to an int and back.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yea... I was hoping there might be some way that I'm simply not aware of.

Comment: @Mars The result of `Math.floatToIntbits(float)` is an `int`. It just represents the value indirectly.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Yes, but it's not the *actual* value as an int, like 100.0 == 100. You can send it as an int, but you can't work with it like it's the value as an int.